# SQL Dynamic partition in count function

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014, sqlreportingservice

I have a stored procedure that is being used with reporting services and the report has a few user filters that are passing values into the stored procedure. Because of these parameters the count for what is displayed changes so I want to use them in the partition to change the count. I tried the following which does not work.

**EDIT:**

The count is done on ss_number but not on @SearchBy. So if I have

```
SS#       |    Name    |    City  |  Amount

123456789 | Mike Smith | Trenton | 100.00

123456789 | Mike Smith | Trenton | 200.00

123456789 | Mike Smith | Jackson | 100.00
```

My count is 3 even though @SearchBy = City and I am filtering on Trenton.

```
CASE WHEN @SearchBy = 'Product Name' THEN count(ss_number) OVER (PARTITION BY ss_number, @SearchBy)
```

Right now I am using a case statement but it has slowed my query down considerably.

Here is the code without the case statement attempting to use the variable in my partition.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_My_sp]
@SearchBy VARCHAR(MAX), 
@SearchString VARCHAR(MAX),
@SearchNum Int,
@ClaimDate Datetime2

AS
WITH MyCTE AS
(   
SELECT val.Claim_date
, val.Claim_Status
, val.Status_Desc
, ES_Claim_Status
, val.ss_number
, val.name_field1
, val.street_add1
, val.street_add2
, val.city
, val.state
, val.zip_code_pre
, val.reference_number
, val.Game_Name 
, val.val_agent
, val.home_number
, val.work_phone
, val.county_desc
, o.agent_num
, count(ss_number) OVER (PARTITION BY ss_number, @SearchBy) as count
, prize_amount
FROM Sec_Claims val left outer join vw_owners_concat_agent_num o
ON val.SS_NUMBER = convert(varchar(15),o.SS_NO)
where convert(numeric,prize_amount) >= 600)
SELECT Claim_date
, CASE WHEN agent_num IS NULL THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END as "IsRetailer"
, Claim_Status
, Status_Desc
, ES_Claim_Status
, ss_number
, name_field1
, street_add1
, street_add2
, city
, state
, zip_code_pre
, reference_number
, Game_Name 
, val_agent
, home_number
, work_phone
, county_desc
, agent_num
, count
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name_Field1 ORDER BY Name_Field1) As RowNumber
, convert(decimal(10,2),prize_amount) as prize_amount
, sum(Convert(decimal(9,2),prize_amount)) OVER (PARTITION BY ss_number, Name_Field1) AS prizesum
FROM MyCTE 
WHERE 
    (CASE
        WHEN @SearchBy = 'Agent Number' THEN agent_num
        WHEN @SearchBy = 'SS#' THEN SS_NUMBER
        WHEN @SearchBy = 'Name' THEN Name_Field1
        WHEN @SearchBy = 'Address' THEN STREET_ADD1
        WHEN @SearchBy = 'City' THEN City
        WHEN @SearchBy = 'Claim#' THEN convert(varchar(max),REFERENCE_NUMBER)
        WHEN @SearchBy = 'Validating Retailer' THEN convert(varchar(max),VAL_AGENT)
        WHEN @SearchBy = 'County' THEN COUNTY_DESC
        WHEN @SearchBy = 'Home Phone' THEN convert(varchar(max),HOME_NUMBER)
        WHEN @SearchBy = 'Work Phone' THEN convert(varchar(max),WORK_PHONE)
        WHEN @SearchBy = 'Game Name' THEN GAME_NAME
    END 
    like (@SearchString))
    and
    count>= @SearchNum 
    and
    claim_date > @ClaimDate 
ORDER BY ss_number
```

Comment: You haven't stated why your query doesn't work, so sample data and expected output would really help here. You certainly don't want to partition over a static value... you want to use a column name.

Comment: I have edited the post. Sorry about the formatting but I think you get the idea.

Comment: How are you filtering on Trenton? Is the @SearchBy supposed to be a column name?

Comment: Yes - @SearchBy is a column

Comment: is there another parameter that Trenton is being stored in?

Comment: No- That is the only one.

Comment: Then how are you filtering on Trenton?

Comment: Sorry - just got into work and misunderstood. I have 4 filters in my report SearchBy which is the column to Search on. SearchString is the value in that column. Then there is Count which is the number of records so that the user can filter on customers with more than the selected number and Date.

Answer (score 0):

your query is slowing down because, as you can imagine, the "case" statement needs to be evaluated for every row, being in a Select statement. 
This means that if your query is loading many rows you put a lot of overhead. 
 
I see two different approaches to solve your issue. I don't love any of them but they works :)

FIRST SOLUTION 
use a IF ... ELSE to cover all you possible inputs.
This means that you'll have to write many times the same query just to differentiate it in one line of code.  
This means code becomes rendundant and basically not maintaniable

SECOND SOLUTION 
Build a dynamic query. 
You can write something like this

```
DECLARE @myQuery nvarchar(max)
SET @myQuery = 'Select '
if @SearchBy = 'Product Name'
  SET @myQuery= @myQuery + 'count(ss_number) OVER (PARTITION BY ss_number, @SearchBy)'
ELSE
  .... --put here your second case
END

SET @myQuery= @myQuery + 'FROM ... WHERE ...'
EXECUTE spexecute_sql @myQuery
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use "Case" inside Over statement:

```
Declare @SearchBy varchar(255)
SET @SearchBy = 'Product Name'

Select count(ss_number)
            OVER (PARTITION BY ss_number,
                               Case @SearchBy
                                    When 'Product Name' then [Name]
                                    When 'City Name'    then [City]
                                    When 'Product Name' then cast([Amount] as varchar(255))
                               END) t     
    from (VALUES (123456789,'Mike Smith','Trenton',100.00)
                ,(123456789,'Mike Smith','Trenton',200.00)
                ,(123456789,'Mike Smith','Jackson',100.00)
         ) as t([ss_number],Name,City,Amount)
```

Comment: I will try it. Will having the CASE inside the OVER improve performance from what I currently have which is CASE WHEN @SearchBy = 'City' THEN count(ss_Fid_number) OVER (PARTITION BY ss_fid_number, City)?

Comment: add extra "Case" inside count   ->  count(CASE @SearchBy when 'City' THEN ss_Fid_number when 'Product Name' then ss_number else NULL end) over(...)

Answer (score 0):

Judging by what you want, you are first going to need Dynamic SQL. With that being said, you can use `row_number()`. I still don't understand your extra partition by, but you can just add it to the example below. You can run this, and it will print out the command that is going to be executed.

```
--create procedure yourProc(
--                          @SearchBY varchar(64)           --Column to search / filter by
--                          ,@SearchString varchar(256)     --Values to limit column above by
--                          ,@Count int                     --limit the count per each SSN
--                          ,@Date datetime)                
--as

--begin

declare     @SearchBY varchar(64)       = 'City'            --Column to search / filter by
declare     @SearchString varchar(256)  = 'Trenton'         --Values to limit column above by
declare     @Count int                  = 3                 --limit the count per each SSN
declare     @Date datetime              = '12/25/2017'

declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = 

'with cte as(
    select
        ss_number
        ,Name
        ,City
        ,Amount
        ,row_number() over (partition by ss_number order by (select 1)) as RN
    from
        YourTable
    where
        SomeDateColumn >= ''' + convert(varchar(10),@Date,112) +
        ''' and ' + @SearchBY + ' = ''' + @SearchString +
        ''')
 select *
 from cte
 where ss_number in 
 (select distinct ss_number from cte where RN >= ' + cast(@Count as varchar(16)) + ')
 '

print(@SQL)
--exec(@SQL)
--end
```

Here is a working example: http://rextester.com/BPWOXH7777

Comment: The problem with this solution is it will only return records with a row number greater than the count. If I select the count of 5 in my report but someone has 40 records, I need it to return all 40, not just those with a row number >= 5. When you say "extra partition" I am not sure what you mean. I have updated my original post with my sp.

Comment: It will return all 40 @Scottdg. As you can see, the clause is where ss_number in (select ... where RN >= @count). That means, if a ss_number is part of the group that has a RN >= 5 all records for that ss_number will be returned. Run it and see....

Comment: Thanks - I read that incorrectly. But this isn't working either. I have an individual with 6 claims. Three of them for the same game. If I filter by game name and enter the value for that game and a search number = 5 I should only get back those with 5 or more claims for that game. I am still getting results for people who may only have one claim for that game but at least 5 claims in the data set.

Comment: @Scottdg You must have built your query wrong. The one i posted, the initial CTE will limit the results according to the column name and value you passed in. Then, for this result set, it will apply a row_number. Then, the final select will only pull the ss_number who have >= the number you passed in. The query is correct. Can you post what you are trying?

Comment: I added my original query in my original post.

Comment: Well I told you how it should be done but I guess it will just have to remain slow since you insist on your way.

Comment: Sorry - I had just posted the original query I think before you posted this solution. Correct me if I am wrong but it appears to me as if much of what you wrote is the same. I moved my row number into the CTE and then changed the where clause to what you have. If you can't/don't want to help any longer I understand but I wasn't trying to be difficult. I will play around with your solution again and see if I can get it to work. Thanks again.

Comment: It appears as if the reason it is not working is the same reason why count is not working. The row number/count needs to be based on the combination of both the SS# and the SearchBy or else I can have someone with 20 rows but for 18 of them he loved in Trenton and 2 he lived in Jackson. If I search for Jackson and a count >= 5 those two rows are being returned because the row count is equal to 20.

Comment: Not using my query it wouldn't. The cte would limit the rows to only where he lived in jackson and thus, the row_number would top out at 2. Then, in the sub-query this person wouldn't be returned if you specified the count of >= 5

Comment: @Scottdg here is proof.  http://rextester.com/BPWOXH7777 Notice that John has more than 9 total rows... but doesn't have 9 rows for City Jackson, thus he isn't returned